# Как изменить MySQL запрос, чтобы получить значение два раза по разным критериям

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть таблица **users** (пользователи)  и таблица **tasks** (задачи).

Они связаны таблицей **tasks_executors** с полями **task_id** и **user_id** для определения исполнителя задачи.

и таблицей  **tasks_creators** с полями **task_id** и **user_id**  для определения создателя задачи.

Написал запрос для выборки полей по исполнителю задачи.

Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить запрос чтобы получить ещё создателя задачи c помощью таблицы **tasks_creators**.

Получается, что нужно получить значение **user.fullname** два раза по разным критериям и как то записать в массив.

Это мой первый учебный проект. Не могу нигде найти похожие запросы.

Собственно, вся функция с запросом целиком.
Для работы с SQL использую PDO.
Спасибо.

```
public static function getTasksByUser($user, $status='active')
{
    $db = DataBase::getConnect();

    $sql = 'SELECT t.id, t.title, t.description, t.deadline, t.status, 
                   u.username, u.fullname AS executor
            FROM tasks_executors te
            INNER JOIN tasks t 
            ON t.id = te.task_id
            INNER JOIN users u 
            ON u.id = te.user_id
            WHERE te.user_id =' . $user
            . ' AND t.statu s =' . "\"$status\"";


    $res = $db->prepare($sql);
    $res->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $res->execute();

    $tasks = [];

    $count = 0;

    foreach ($res as $row) {
        $tasks[] = [
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'title' => $row['title'],
            'description' => $row['description'],
            'deadline' => $row['deadline'],
            'executor' => $row['executor'],
            'creator' => $row['creator'],
        ];
        $count++;
    }

    $tasks['count'] = $count;

    return $tasks;
}
```

Comment: Просто ещё один JOIN сделайте к таблице users с другим условием: INNER JOIN user taskcreator ON taskcreator.id = ....

Comment: Скажите, а вас вообще устраивает текущая структура базы и запрос? Ведь по вашей структуре получается, что одну задачу могут одновременно делать несколько исполнителей и выводя список из вашего запроса у вас задачи могут дублироваться.

Comment: Вроде устраивает.  task_id в таблице tasks_executors является первичным ключом. В запросе не уверен. Есть варианты получше?

Comment: Однозначно плюс товарищу за то что 'Для работы с SQL использую PDO'. Вот только еще объясните, с какой именно целью Вы сначала выбираете из базы лишние поля? это для того чтобы затем в цикле от них избавиться?) Для подсчета же количества элементов массива следует использовать встроенную функцию count - одна из немногих функций для работы с массивами, которая работает быстрее (!), чем for и foreach.

Comment: Да, поля действительно лишние. Забыл исправить когда вопрос задавал. Спасибо за совет использовать функцию count. Это мой первый проект на php, поэтому только учусь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за подсказку! Решил задачу так:

```
public static function getTasksByUser($user, $status='active')
{
    $db = DataBase::getConnect();

    $sql = 'SELECT t.id, t.title, t.description, t.deadline, t.status, 
                    u.username, u.fullname AS executor, creator.id, creator.fullname AS creator
            FROM tasks_executors te
            INNER JOIN tasks t 
            ON t.id=te.task_id
            INNER JOIN users u
            ON te.user_id = u.id
            INNER JOIN tasks_creators tc
            ON tc.task_id = t.id
            INNER JOIN users creator
            ON creator.id = tc.user_id
            WHERE te.user_id=' . $user
            . ' AND t.status=' . "\"$status\"";



    $res = $db->prepare($sql);
    $res->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $res->execute();

    $tasks = [];

    $count = 0;

    foreach ($res as $row) {
        $tasks[] = [
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'title' => $row['title'],
            'description' => $row['description'],
            'deadline' => $row['deadline'],
            'executor' => $row['executor'],
            'creator' => $row['creator'],
        ];
        $count++;
    }

    $tasks['count'] = $count;

    return $tasks;
}
```